# How to mutate the values in a R list object?

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list named "binom" that looks as follows:

[image: binom]

**"estimate_"** values are probabilities that I want to reverse (to do a calculation "1-value"). How to mutate these values in this list?

I googled but did not find a code for doing this. I need the list afterwards as a list for plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at `?base::transform` or `?dplyr::mutate`

You will first need to subset your list to the element you want to manipulate:

```
library(dplyr)

binom[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(newcol = 1 - estimate_)
```

You can learn more about data transformation [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html)

In the future, it's helpful to provide a mock dataset with your question instead of a screenshot, so that people have something to work with when attempting to answer your questions.

Comment: you may want to save back to the list, so this may work better   `binorm[[1]] <- binorm[[1]] %>% 
  mutate(newCol = 1- estimate_)`

Comment: Thank you to both of you! This helped a lot!